# Как можно в php написать запрос для БД mysql чтобы добавить к существующим данным значение

Tags: php, mysql

Есть бд и сайт, с сайта выводятся данные в бд через форму.Мне нужно чтобы я мог с сайта добавить данные в существующее значение , к примеру: Есть таблица клиент, у него атрибуты - номер, название компании, прозвон. Если в номере и в названии компании есть данные, то прозвон выставляет значения с сайта.Вопрос, как добавить к телефону и к названию компании любой статус (Прозвонили/Не прозвонили).

Comment: Попробовал сделать вот так: $sql = "UPDATE Contagent(Prozvon) VALUES ('$prozvon') WHERE Contagent . id_contr VALUES ('$id')"; , но увы и ах, ошибка синтексиса (Хотел фильтровать с помощью айди и добавлять туда значения)

Comment: @InDevX Вот такая ошибка :You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(Prozvon) VALUES ('Прозвонили')WHERE id_contr = 3' at line 1

Comment: `$sql = "UPDATE Contagent SET Prozvon = '$prozvon' WHERE id_contr = $id";`

Comment: Спасибо!Вы очень помогли)